# scypy.signal.decimate() freezes GUI

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, qthread, resampling

I have to plot signals with big number of samples (up to 4e6 samples). I am using python 2.7, Qt 4.8 and pyqtgraph 0.9.10.

I did something like this:

1. Generate signals and decimate them (in separate QThread)
2. Plot signals and call setDownsample() and clipToView() (methods of pyqtgraph)

The problem is that GUI freezes when QThread for decimate calculates. Here is my code:

```
class TestDecimate(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TestDecimate, self).__init__(parent)

        self.decimate_thread = GenerateBigPlotThread()

        layout = QGridLayout()

        graph_widget = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()
        graph_layout = graph_widget.addLayout()

        self.p = graph_layout.addPlot(title="Plot 2", col=1, row=2)
        self.curve1 = self.p.plot([], pen=(255, 0, 0))
        self.curve2 = self.p.plot([], pen=(255, 255, 0))
        self.curve3 = self.p.plot([], pen=(255, 0, 255))
        self.curve4 = self.p.plot([], pen=(0, 0, 255))
        self.p.showGrid(True, True, 0.3)

        self.legend = pg.LegendItem(offset=(-10,10))
        self.legend.addItem(self.curve1, name="Test")
        self.legend.addItem(self.curve2, name="Test1")
        self.legend.addItem(self.curve3, name="Test2")
        self.legend.addItem(self.curve4, name="Test3")
        self.legend.setParentItem(self.p.getViewBox())

        self.start_pb = QPushButton("Generate")

        layout.addWidget(graph_widget, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.start_pb, 2, 1)

        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.start_pb.clicked.connect(self.start_thread_for_decimate)
        self.decimate_thread.newData.connect(self.set_data)

    def set_data(self, y, z, n, m):
        print "Plotting"
        self.curve1.setData(y)
        self.curve2.setData(z)
        self.curve3.setData(n)
        self.curve4.setData(m)

        self.p.setDownsampling(ds=True, auto=True, mode='peak')
        self.p.setClipToView(clip=True)
        self.p.getViewBox().enableAutoRange(axis=ViewBox.XYAxes)
        print "Plotting done"


    def start_thread_for_decimate(self):
        self.decimate_thread.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
     app = QApplication(sys.argv)
     main = TestDecimate()
     main.show()
     sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thread for calculation and decimation:

```
class GenerateBigPlotThread(QThread):

    newData = QtCore.pyqtSignal("PyQt_PyObject","PyQt_PyObject","PyQt_PyObject","PyQt_PyObject")

    def __init__(self,*arg,**kwargs):
        super(GenerateBigPlotThread, self).__init__(*arg,**kwargs)

    def run(self):

        self.num_points = 4e6

        x = np.arange(self.num_points)
        y = np.sin(3.14159 * x * 10/self.num_points)
        z = np.cos(3.14159 * x * 10/self.num_points)
        n = np.sin(3.14159 * x * 5/self.num_points)
        m = np.cos(3.14159 * x * 5/self.num_points)
        print "Decimate"
        y = decimate(y, 4, ftype='fir')
        z = decimate(z, 4, ftype='fir')
        n = decimate(n, 4, ftype='fir')
        m = decimate(m, 4, ftype='fir')
        print "Done!"

        self.newData.emit(y, z, n, m)
```

When thread is started the best way to see the problem is to move legend. 
Also, I tried scipy.signal.resample (4e6 samples to 1e6 samples) instead of decimate and the same problem is occurred.
Can someone tell me what is the reason for this kind of behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem was in version of scipy. I had scipy 0.13.2 and after I upgraded to 0.17.0, problem seems to be solved. Still, I would like to know why something like this was possible in the first place.